# What is the right timing for setting the opacity of a view's background

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, opacity, alpha

I try to set the background alpha of my custom linearLayout.

I have tried:

```
//ctor
protected MyView(
      Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, @LayoutRes int layout) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, this);
        getBackground().setAlpha(128);

}
```

and

```
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        getBackground().setAlpha(128);
      }
    });
```

but the background is still null

I have tried

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onPreDraw() {
    vto.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
    getBackground().setAlpha(128);

    return true;
  }
});
```

but i get
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: This ViewTreeObserver is not alive, call getViewTreeObserver() again`

What is the right timing to get the background and change its alpha (opacity)?

Comment: `view.post(runnable)` ensure that it will get called after drawing view is complete . You can try this .`getBackground()` returns a `Drawable` this can be null if did not set one ..

Comment: does `getBackground()` return  a view ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried android:alpha="0.5" property in your xml itself for your linear layout?

Comment: yes, but it seems the items items change. not the background

Comment: than first change apha of your background drawable, than set that drawable as the background for your linear layout like this:

<pre>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/background" android:alpha="0.4"/>
<code>

android:background="@drawable/bg"